# Class type mismatch using money.php library

Tags: php

I'm using money.php to handle some calculations, but I'm getting errors I don't understand.  I have a class extending another class, both with the exact same constructor, copy and pasted, but in my error log I see the following

```
Declaration of FirstClass::__construct($taxMode, $year, Money\\Money $grossIncome, $deductions) must be compatible with SecondClass::__construct($taxMode, $year, Money $grossIncome, $deductions)
```

Both constructors look like the following

```
public function __construct($taxMode, $year, Money $grossIncome = null, $deductions)
```

and both have  the following at the top of the file

```
    require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
    use Money\Currency;
    use Money\Money;
```

I'm at a complete loss and would love any help anyone can offer

Comment: What's the namespace of each class? Do you have any `namespace` in either file?

Comment: You might *think* you can double your money like that, but it won't work. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your constructor:

The first one: Money\Money $grossIncome

The second one: Money $grossIncome

Your import of Money class is bad maybe.

Comment: Both constructors use the exact same line that I posted above. The question is why does one expect Money\Money and the other doesn't?

Comment: As Scopey mentioned it could be namespace problem.